# compare two arrays and find out changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix

I have got an array of 3 arrays, like matrix 3x3 named _matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
end I have another matrix 3x3 named _newMatrix
I need a function that will compare this two matrix and give me index of elements that changed, or something that changed. Is there a straight way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array comparison is a fun problem. Nested arrays make this even more interesting.

The first, most important question, is what kind of output are you looking for. For example (and I'm using 2x2 matrices for brevity), do you want a third matrix that represents the differences?

```
[[2, 3],
 [4, 5]]
```

diff'd with

```
[[3, 6],
 [5, 2]]
```

could be:

```
[[1, 3],
 [2, -3]]
```

That seems like a reasonable idea. Let's look at how we might implement that.

```
- (NSArray *)matrixByFindingDifferenceBetweenFirstMatrix:(NSArray *)firstMatrix secondMatrix:(NSArray *)secondMatrix {
    NSMutableArray *differenceMatrix = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < firstMatrix.count; i++) {
        NSArray *row = [firstMatrix objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *secondMatrixRow = [secondMatrix objectAtIndex:i];
        NSMutableArray *differenceRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int j = 0; j < row.count; j++) {
            NSNumber *currentValue = [row objectAtIndex:j];
            NSNumber *newValue = [secondMatrixRow objectAtIndex:j];
            NSNumber *difference = @(newValue.intValue - currentValue.intValue);
            [differenceRow addObject:difference];
        }
        [differenceMatrix addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:differenceRow];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:differenceMatrix];
}
```

That makes sense. I don't know if it's what you want, but the core of matrix comparison lies in the nested iteration (obviously O(n^2), so avoid very big matrixes)

EDIT: Just getting the index paths of changed elements.

```
- (NSArray *)changedIndexPathsBetweenFirstMatrix:(NSArray *)firstMatrix secondMatrix:(NSArray *)secondMatrix {
    NSMutableArray *changedIndexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < firstMatrix.count; i++) {
        NSArray *row = [firstMatrix objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *secondMatrixRow = [secondMatrix objectAtIndex:i];
        for(int j = 0; j < row.count; j++) {
            NSNumber *currentValue = [row objectAtIndex:j];
            NSNumber *newValue = [secondMatrixRow objectAtIndex:j];
            if(![currentValue isEqual:newValue]) {
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:j]; // Row is technically "column" in the sense of matrixes, and section is the matrix's row.
                [changedIndexes addObject:path];
            }
        }
        [differenceMatrix addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:differenceRow];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:differenceMatrix];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have matrix 3x3 ( two matrix) for me it would be helpful to know indexes of elements what are changed.

I tried to subtract this two matrixes but my solution didn't come true

Comment: Ah, so you're just interested in know what indexes are different. We might want to use NSIndexPath here. NSIndexPath was conceived for use in UITableViews and the like, but they're useful in this case. See the second code block in my (about to be) edited answer -- this may help you.

Comment: I was mistaken about NSIndexPath's conception, it's been around longer than iOS, but the additions added by UIKit for use in TableViews make it easier to create an instance with the kind of data you're expecting. I'd recommend the [NSIndexPath docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be an example way to do it. If you need help with that, ask again. But without any effort shown by you, you won´t get any more help than that.

```
- (NSArray*) getDifferencesBetween:(NSArray*)first and:(NSArray*)second {
  // create a NSMutableArray * as the return value      
  // get the dimension of the matrixes by first.count and first[0].count
  // iterate over the matrix in two nested for loops 
  // check if the value in first[x][y] differ from second[x][y]
  // if so, add the index (x + y * first.count) to the return value
  // return the return value (the NSMutableArray*)
}
```